# My for-each implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, array

I have implemented for-each as in jQuery, this is the code below,

```
var $ = (function(){
   var obj = {};
   return obj;
})();

$.each = function(collection,fn){

    if(collection.constructor.name === 'Array'){
        for(var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++){
            fn.call(this,collection[i]);
        }   
    }else{
        for(var prop in collection){
            fn.call(this,collection[prop]);
        }
    }


};


$.each([1,2,3,7,8],function(num){
    console.log(num * 2);
});

$.each(['A','B','C'],function(char){
    console.log(char);
});

$.each({ 
    name : 'Rahul Shivsharan', 
    department : 'Computer Science' 
},function(value){
       console.log(value);
});
```

The output of the code is

```
2
4
6
14
16 
A
B
C
Rahul Shivsharan
Computer Science
```

Please review my jQuery style for-each implementation, and let me know your feedback

Comment: [Review](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/289curze/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `non-array` iterator would normally be written as:

```
for (var prop in collection) {
  if (collection.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    fn.call(this,collection[prop]);
  } 
}
```

to avoid iterating over non-direct properties. See     https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

Answer (score 0):

To extend jQuery EACH I think it will confuse other developers especially during the maintenance period without you. To be better looping your collections you may need to use UnderscoreJS vs Lodash. They come with many useful collection functions.

Comment: I don't think the OP wants to extend jQuery. He is writing his own jQuery like library.